# c# byte[] → string → byte[] issue

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unicode

Another strange question from me.

I have this code:

```
byte[] chks = Get64bitData();
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(chks);
byte[] bts = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

Method `Get64bitData` returns **8** bytes array, then array got converted to string. 
And then code converts string to byte array again, BUT new array is now has **16** bytes!

What type of hell is this and how avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure the data you're getting from `Get64bitData` is actually UTF8 text?

Comment: You need to show us the contents of  `chks`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any random byte[] can not be converted to text safely as you have seen. Use *Convert.ToBase64String* or *BitConverter.ToString* to convert byte arrays to string.

```
byte[] chks = Get64bitData();
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(chks);
byte[] bts = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
```

or using *SoapHexBinary* class in *System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001*

```
byte[] chks = Get64bitData();
string str = new SoapHexBinary(chks).ToString();
byte[] bts = SoapHexBinary.Parse(str).Value;
```